# spcascade dropdowns

Tags: spservices

I am trying to implement the spcascade dropdown for achieving caascading. My cascading is achieved but somehow i get the following error on btn OK Click,

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in configuration or `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Please help as it is urgent :(

Comment: That error isn't something thet I recognize, and it isn't caused by SPServices directly. Can you post the script you are using to call SPCascadeDropdowns? Does the form submit corretly without the call to SPServices?

Comment: Sorry about submitting the above comment as an answer initially. Poor typing skillz on my part.